# SQL Server 2000 msdb database loading/suspect

Tags: sql-server, database

My SQL Server recently suffered a raid controller/hard drive crash. After getting my hard drive problem corrected I soon found that some of my databases were (suspect) namely msdb.

I am not a DBA by any means however am somewhat familiar with the daily SQL activities that happen on my server. So I restored from backup, and tried to bring my msdb database online.

It is now forever stuck in (Loading\Suspect) and I am unable to script backups for my important databases.  I can recreate all of the backup plans etc if i can somehow get a working msdb.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently using:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2000
- Version:  8.00.194

Answer (score 2):

Follow the directions in this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180500).  It has to do with the suspect database caused by a missing or new device.  I hope this helps.

If that doesn't work, you will have to recreate the MSDB database yourself.

1. Detach the damaged msdb. You can't just detach msdb because you're not allowed to detach system databases. However, you can if you start the server with trace flag 3608. I did this by shutting down the server, navigating to the directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn' and doing the following: start sqlservr.exe -c -T3608
2. Move or rename the damaged msdb files (msdbdata.mdf and msdblog.ldf in the 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data' directory)
3. Run the instmsdb.sql script in the 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Install' directory
4. Shutdown and restart the server without the 3608 trace flag